# Load page contents and links inside of div;

Tags: javascript, ajax

Okay basically what I'm trying to achieve is load links that are clicked inside of the `targetDiv` inside the div not load on the whole page; Below is the script I'm currently using.

```
<div id = "targetDiv"></div>

<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#targetDiv').load('/test.php');
});
</script>
```

So the problem I'm having is that when a link is clicked which is loaded in the `targetDiv`the whole page loads and the user is taken from the original page and taken to the new page; and what I want to happen is the new page load within the `targetDiv`.

Comment: [update] I want it to act as an iframe in the sense that links clicked load within the frame; but load within a div if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Can you show us what your links look like?

Comment: @showdev sure on the `test.php` page which is loaded in the `targetDiv` my links look like `<a href="/home.php">Home</a>`

Comment: Sounds like an AJAX request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a click handler that prevents the default event and also uses the href to `load()` again

```
$(function(){
    $('#targetDiv').on('click', 'a', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#targetDiv').load(this.href);    
    });
});
```

This is a delegated listener to account for future `<a>` that don't exist at run time

Comment: Can I just confirm im using this correct as I cant get it to load the page; on this line im using  `$('#targetDiv').load('/text.php');` however its not loading anything in the div.

Comment: but that would always load the same page. You said you wanted to load links in the content is what I understood.

Comment: oh right, thats great I could do it that way also, I'm really sorry for one last question but what would a link look like if i wanted to load within the targetdiv, I'm really sorry. so for example if a link was placed outside the div to load within the div

Comment: so for example if a link was placed outside the div to load within the div

Comment: You need to either target it by class or by parent like `$('#nav a').click..`

Comment: Thankyou so much :) really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to what you are trying to do is bind click events to anchor tags inside your target div and explicitly load the content to that div again.

```
$( "#targetDiv a" ).click(function() {
  $('#targetDiv').load(this.href);
});
```

As it separate note, it seems like you may have been expecting iframe-like behavior, which may be the element you go with for this.

Comment: Those elements don't exist at run time

Comment: I also suggest [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the click event, so the link wont be followed in its native manner.

Comment: Okay I don't know why but am i using this correctly because the page isn't being loaded into the div, here; `$( "#targetDiv a" ).click(function() {$('#targetDiv').load('/text.php');});`

Comment: @LewisTyler if I understand correctly you intend to click a link from that text.php content (presuming it loaded in your document ready function) and then load it in the same div (overwriting what was in that div before). The code that I intended (which is proper in the answer by @charlieftl) simply does the latter, taking any clickable link and loading it into your div. In that particular use case it's as simple as appending his answer to your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason why this is not working is due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). If you attempt my code snippet while running a PHP web server it'll work seamlessly.

It appears you're missing an event listener for the click event. Assuming your  has id="link":

**jQuery**

```
$("#link").click("click", function() {
  // Do the AJAX request
  $.ajax({
    url: "/text.php"
  })
  .done(function(data) { // data fetched from php file
    // Load data into div
    $('#targetDiv').html(data);
  });

  /*
  // this would also work
  $("#targetDiv").load('text.php');
  */
})

<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

Comment: `load()` that OP is a  shortcut method for `$.ajax`

Comment: when I use this script it doesn't load the text.php document into the targetDiv?